# How do you get the value of a "embed"?

Tags: podio

I have a link field called `lien`. When I get it from the API through the `Item` it belongs to, I receive the following array:

```
[lien] => Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [embed] => 49935230
        [file] => 129256002
    )
)
```

I have no problem with the file.

**How do you get the URL value?**

The `Embeds` documentation: https://developers.podio.com/doc/embeds

A similar issue exists when getting the value of a category field through the `Item` object. It's an array of the selected `option_id`, it doesn't hold the `option_text`. The workaround is to get the corresponding `App` object and search for the `option_text` using the provided `option_id`.

Comment: Are you using a client library? If so which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field's values are returned as a collection of embed objects. You can see documentation at: http://podio.github.io/podio-php/fields/#linkembed-field

E.g.:

```
$item = PodioItem::get_basic(123);
$field_id = 'embed';
$collection = $item->fields[$field_id]->values;

foreach ($collection as $embed) {
  print "Embed id: ".$embed->embed_id;
  print "Embed URL: ".$embed->original_url;
}
```

Comment: That's right. The output I got is from `file_put_contents` of the object. I assume there's an object collection for the category field options as well?

Comment: You can see examples for all field types on that page http://podio.github.io/podio-php/fields/